# Python and Pip not in sync

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, pip

I am working on a remote linux server with python 2.7.6 pre-installed. I want to **upgrade to python 2.7.12** (because I am not able to install some libraries on the 2.7.6 due to some **ssl error** shown below).

I downloaded and compiled from source and installed 2.7.12 and `python2.7` opens 2.7.12. However, I still get an update python version warning while using pip. It seems the pip has not synced with 2.7.12 and continues to serve 2.7.6 and I am not able to find other installations of pip in system.

I just want a working version of python2.7.x with pip/pip2/pip2.7 working properly.

```
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:318: SNIMissingWarning: An HTTPS request has been made, but the SNI (Subject Name Indication) extension to TLS is not available on this platform. This may cause the server to present an incorrect TLS certificate, which can cause validation failures. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#snimissingwarning.
  SNIMissingWarning
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-8.1.2-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:122: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. You can upgrade to a newer version of Python to solve this. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
```

Comment: Does that machine have openSSL? Most of the times, python gives this warning but still installs the packages. Is it able to install things into your system?

Comment: No, it isn't. I tried installing `sklearn` and it threw lots of exception and now it shows that it is installed. But sklearn is broken and not working.

Comment: Can you install urllib3, pyOpenSSL and openSSL and then try installing packages again?

Comment: @ar7 I've seen this error, and if I remember correctly, it's an issue with an outdated `pip`, as the OP guesses. Upgrading `pip` is usually the solution.

Comment: I don't understand the paths in your error messages though: they seem to point to a recent pip version and a manually installed Python 2. That doesn't indicate Python 2.7.6 to me.

Comment: @ar7 While trying to install those libraries you mentioned I got the same error as above.

Comment: @Evert That's what I also thought. But the pip was failing to install and whatever it installed didn't reflect on 2.7.12. The error message also asked to update the python version. 
It could be that a terminal restart helped for the changes to reflect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade (and automatically reinstall) pip this way:

```
/path/to/python2.7.12 -m pip install pip --upgrade
```

The `-m` flag loads the corresponding module, and in the case of pip will execute `pip` (thanks to [the power of the `__main__` module inside the package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html)).

After installation, your current `pip` should also be up-to-date.

---

Alternatively, you could run

```
/path/to/python2.7.12 /path/to/pip2 install pip --upgrade
```

---

NB: be wary about which `pip` and `python2` you're running: there'll probably be a `/usr/bin/python` and /usr/bin/pip`next to the ones you installed in`/usr/local/`. The ones in`/usr/bin` should just be updated following the standard system updates, if at all.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Evert , just before looking into your solution I tried,

```
curl -O https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
python27 get-pip.py
```

This fixed my issue and I was able to install libraries to `2.7.12` using `pip/pip2.7`

I was earlier trying `python2.7 -m pip install package-name` and I was getting `pip not found`.